# how to refer iframe within iframe

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

I want to refer iframe which is inside another iframe

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="playButton">Play</div>
<div class="flex-active-slide">
<iframe src=""> <!--But refering this-->
  #document
   <html>
      <body>
        <iframe src=""><!--want to refer this iframe -->
          #document
           <html>
              <body>

              </body>
           </html>
        </iframe>
      </body>
   </html>
 <iframe>
   </div>

  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $(".playButton").on('click',function(){
      $(".flex-active-slide iframe")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
    });
  });
```

Comment: Are the frame pages and main page all on same domain? If any one of them is different you won't be able to do what you are asking

Comment: all frame are in same domain

Comment: You cannot nest an iframe inside another iframe

Comment: it is embedded by plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to get inside first frame window once it has loaded:

```
$('iframe').on('load', function(){
  var $secondFrame = $(this).contents().find('iframe');
      $secondFrame.attr('src', someUrl)    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Consider this:

<div class="flex-active-slide">
<iframe class="i1" src=""> <!--But refering this-->
  #document
   <html>
      <body>
        <iframe class="i2" src=""><!--want to refer this iframe -->
          #document
           <html>
              <body>

              </body>
           </html>
        </iframe>
      </body>
   </html>
 <iframe>
   </div>
```

You can access iframe with class "i2" as:

```
var l1 = $(".flex-active-slide .i1")[0];
$(l1.contentDocument).find("iframe.i2");
```

Comment: `l1` is jquery object and has no property `contentDocument`. Would be `l1[0].contentDocument` but can't find inner frame until outer one loads

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I edited the change.
As OP asked just the way to access inner iframe, I tried to mention that.