# replace the url using regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I want to replace the iframe url which is having autoplay=1 to autoplay=0 using reg exp.

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('.playButton').click(function(){
             $('.flex-active-slide iframe').contents().find("iframe")[0].src=src.replace(/\&autoplay\=\d/,"&autoplay="+1);
        });
   $(".close_icon").click(function(){
     $('.flex-active-slide iframe').contents().find("iframe")[0].src=src.replace(/\&autoplay\=\d/,"&autoplay="+0);
  });
       });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="playButton">Play</div><div class="close_icon">Close</div>
<div class="flex-active-slide">
<iframe src=""> 
  #document
   <html>
      <body>
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c?width=640&autoplay=1">
          #document
           <html>
              <body>

              </body>
           </html>
        </iframe>
      </body>
   </html>
 <iframe>
   </div>
```

I want to replay the src.but It is not working

Comment: Yesterday you asked how to access inside first frame and ignored answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/41356414/1175966. Now you are basically back to the same place asking pretty much the same question

Answer (score 0):

Try this : use with `load()` and `attr('src')`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.playButton').click(function(){
           $('.flex-active-slide iframe').load(function(){
           var  iframe_src = $('.flex-active-slide iframe').contents().find("iframe")[0].attr('src');
             $('.flex-active-slide iframe').contents().find("iframe")[0].attr('src',iframe_src.replace(/\&autoplay\=\d/,"&autoplay="+1));
        });
          });
  $(".close_icon").click(function(){
       $('.flex-active-slide iframe').load(function(){
        var iframe_src = $('.flex-active-slide iframe').contents().find("iframe")[0].attr('src');
     $('.flex-active-slide iframe').contents().find("iframe")[0].attr('src' , iframe_src.replace(/\&autoplay\=\d/,"&autoplay="+0));
  });
       });
  })
```

Comment: I caught  TypeError: $(...).contents(...).find(...)[0].attr is not a function

Comment: try with `id` of inner Iframe of iframe and remove the `[0]`